# java replaceLast()

Tags: java, string

Is there `replaceLast()` in Java? I saw there is `replaceFirst()`.

EDIT: If there is not in the SDK, what would be a good implementation?

Comment: People here are way too eager to mark questions duplicates. This question (general replaceAll()) has nothing to do with the question in the "duplicate".

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It could (of course) be done with regex:

```
public class Test {

    public static String replaceLast(String text, String regex, String replacement) {
        return text.replaceFirst("(?s)"+regex+"(?!.*?"+regex+")", replacement);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceLast("foo AB bar AB done", "AB", "--"));
    }
}
```

although a bit *cpu-cycle-hungry* with the look-aheads, but that will only be an issue when working with very large strings (and many occurrences of the regex being searched for).

A short explanation (in case of the regex being `AB`):

```
(?s)     # enable dot-all option
A        # match the character 'A'
B        # match the character 'B'
(?!      # start negative look ahead
  .*?    #   match any character and repeat it zero or more times, reluctantly
  A      #   match the character 'A'
  B      #   match the character 'B'
)        # end negative look ahead
```

### EDIT

> Sorry to wake up an old post. But this is only for non-overlapping instances. 
>   For example `.replaceLast("aaabbb", "bb", "xx");` returns `"aaaxxb"`, not `"aaabxx"`

True, that could be fixed as follows:

```
public class Test {

    public static String replaceLast(String text, String regex, String replacement) {
        return text.replaceFirst("(?s)(.*)" + regex, "$1" + replacement);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceLast("aaabbb", "bb", "xx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to wake up an old post. But this is only for non-overlapping instances.

For example `.replaceLast("aaabbb", "bb", "xx");` returns `"aaaxxb"`, not `"aabxx"`

Comment: A class implementing this: https://github.com/Fewlaps/quitnow-email-suggester/blob/master/src/com/fewlaps/quitnowemailsuggester/util/StringUtils.java

And its test: https://github.com/Fewlaps/quitnow-email-suggester/blob/master/src/test/StringUtilsTest.java

BTW, thanks, @BartKiers!

Answer (score 47):

If you don't need regex, here's a substring alternative.

```
public static String replaceLast(String string, String toReplace, String replacement) {
    int pos = string.lastIndexOf(toReplace);
    if (pos > -1) {
        return string.substring(0, pos)
             + replacement
             + string.substring(pos + toReplace.length());
    } else {
        return string;
    }
}
```

Testcase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(replaceLast("foobarfoobar", "foo", "bar")); // foobarbarbar
    System.out.println(replaceLast("foobarbarbar", "foo", "bar")); // barbarbarbar
    System.out.println(replaceLast("foobarfoobar", "faa", "bar")); // foobarfoobar
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah - just that this doesn't replace regexps... (think s/ab*c/d/)

Comment: @Thomas, it also states "If you don't need regex..." in top of answer :)

Answer (score 23):

use replaceAll and add a dollar sign right after your pattern:

```
replaceAll("pattern$", replacement);
```

Comment: This only works if the last instance is the last value. i.e.,

s = s.replaceAll(".1$", ".2");

hi.1 would be hi.2, but if I did hi.12 it would still be hi.12


"hi.1" -> "hi.2" (good)

"hi.12" -> "hi.12" (Bad)

"hi.11" -> "hi..2" (Bad)

"hi.111" -> "hi.1.2" (Bad)

"hi.1111" -> "hi.11.2" (Bad)


The good thing for me is, I need it to be the last instance, and it will be the last value :).

Just wanted to note this for those who might find this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can combine [`StringUtils.reverse()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#reverse%28java.lang.String%29) with `String.replaceFirst()`

Comment: abcdefg will be gfedcba, you have to modify your regex to replace the "reversed" target.

Answer (score 9):

Use StringUtils from apache:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.chomp(value, ignoreChar);
```

Comment: This is (or will be) [deprecated](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#chomp-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Comment: deprecated in favour of `StringUtils.removeEnd` which works fine.

Answer (score 8):

See for yourself: [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Or is your question actually "How do I implement a `replaceLast()`?"

Let me attempt an implementation (this should behave pretty much like `replaceFirst()`, so it should support regexes and backreferences in the replacement String):

```
public static String replaceLast(String input, String regex, String replacement) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
       return input;
    }
    int lastMatchStart=0;
    do {
      lastMatchStart=matcher.start();
    } while (matcher.find());
    matcher.find(lastMatchStart);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: @willcode: it was intended as a semi-honest, semi-smug question ;-)

Comment: Yes I did not see it as being pure evil :)

Comment: **Smart!** I was thinking I might have to loop over the string twice with the `matcher`, but doing `find(int)` is way smarter. I wonder why Java designers did not implement this in `String`...

Comment: This answer works where you want to replace an undetermined number of characters `"[^a-z]+"` where as the most upvoted one fails this case.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You could do `reverse` / `replaceFirst` / `reverse`, but it's a bit expensive.

Comment: + you will need to reverse the search string, so that's 3 reverse operations.

Comment: Not even *"reverse the search string"* because it's a regex, you will have to **modify** the regex to cater to the reversed string (reversed regex is most likely garbage).

Comment: ...err... or write the regex correctly (i.e., to match the reversed string) in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

If the inspected string is so that

```
myString.endsWith(substringToReplace) == true
```

you also can do

```
myString=myString.replaceFirst("(.*)"+myEnd+"$","$1"+replacement)
```

Comment: Why did you capture? Can't you just `myString=myString.replaceFirst(myEnd+"$", replacement)`?

Answer (score 0):

it is slow, but works:3

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

public static String replaceLast(String str, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    str = StringUtils.reverse(str);
    str = str.replaceFirst(StringUtils.reverse(oldValue), StringUtils.reverse(newValue));
    str = StringUtils.reverse(str);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

split the haystack by your needle using a lookahead regex and replace the last element of the array, then join them back together :D

```
String haystack = "haystack haystack haystack";
String lookFor = "hay";
String replaceWith = "wood";

String[] matches = haystack.split("(?=" + lookFor + ")");
matches[matches.length - 1] = matches[matches.length - 1].replace(lookFor, replaceWith);
String brandNew = StringUtils.join(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have encountered such a problem, but I use this method:

```
public static String replaceLast2(String text,String regex,String replacement){
    int i = text.length();
    int j = regex.length();

    if(i<j){
        return text;
    }

    while (i>j&&!(text.substring(i-j, i).equals(regex))) {
        i--;
    }

    if(i<=j&&!(text.substring(i-j, i).equals(regex))){
        return text;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(text.substring(0, i-j));
    sb.append(replacement);
    sb.append(text.substring(i));

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really works good. Just add your string where u want to replace string  in s and in place of "he" place the sub string u want to replace and in place of "mt" place the sub string you want in your new string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindSubStr 
{
 public static void main(String str[])
 {
    Scanner on=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=on.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String st1=s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("he"));
    String st2=s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("he"));
    String n=st2.replace("he","mt");

    System.out.println(st1+n);
 }

}
```